# Контакт с программой на Python через сервер на TOR

Tags: python, python-3.x, веб-сервер, tor

Опишу, что мне примерно нужно.
Я хочу, чтобы программа работала удалённо и я мог посылать ей команды.То есть как бы общаться с ней и получать от неё информацию.
Всё это через сервер на TOR. Как это можно осуществить, используя библиотеку Torpy?
То есть нужно создавать сайт на TOR?
И как использовать для этого Torpy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Всё это через сервер на TOR.

> То есть нужно создавать сайт на TOR?

Насколько я понял,вам нужно сделать get<strike>/post</strike> запрос к onion домену.
Вам поможет [**TORPY**](https://pypi.org/project/torpy/) и [***TORPYGIT***](https://github.com/torpyorg/torpy/blob/master/tests/integration/test_integration.py)
(Так же можно делать это с помощью requests и встроенного в него proxy - **[ВОТ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43682909/connect-to-onion-websites-on-tor-using-python)** )

Comment: То есть я должен создать сайт в TOR и разместить там информацию. И программа сможет сделать запрос и получить её?

Comment: Да,всё верно. Вы можете получить содержимое страницы сайта в доменной зоне onion.  **Я хочу, чтобы программа работала удалённо и я мог посылать ей команды.** Что за программа? На сервере или на клиентской стороне?